# How to call the same function in different view in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I create a customer class in my backbone project :

```
function Cart(){
    //some working code here
    this.updateQtyLabel = function(labelName){
        $('#'+ labelName).text(getTotalQtyItemCart());
    };
}
```

I called this function in my `Home` view :

```
var myCart = new Cart();
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function() {
        myCart.updateQtyLabel("qtyCart");
   },
   //..... code of home view 
}
```

Here is block of html in index.html:

```
<div id="qtyCart"></div>
```

So the `updateQtyLable()` only work in home view of the header in my web page.

Could anyone give me some ideas, how can/where should I call the `updateQtyLable()` to make it work for all page of my web site.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no globally metohod to call some function for all views.
You can therefore write base object for your all views, and call method in their initialize method. Something like this:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () { ..call here what you need...}
});

var HomeView = BaseView.extend({
    initialize: function () {
      BaseView.prototype.initialize.call(this);
      ..other code here...
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I put `BaseView` in the other file, and call it to use in `HomeView` using `require.js` ?